# Why might this be too localized?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

This has a couple of close votes as *too localized*. As someone who personally is quite interested in the answer to this question, since I've heard of the problem before and would like to know how to solve it, I don't feel this is too localized. (I do think we may need to get more information from the OP to give more answers, however.)

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/174804/i-cant-copy-to-external-drive-read-only-error-cant-change-permissions-even-f

Why might this be too localized?

<sup>(All perspectives welcome, but as the wording of the title suggests, I'm particularly interested in answers from people who believe it *should* be closed as too localized.)</sup>

Comment: No updates nearly 2 months perhaps?

Comment: @JorgeCastro That makes sense...does anyone know if we have a question (or other resource) reflecting community consensus on how long a question should go without updates, to become a good candidate for closure as abandoned?

Comment: We don't, if I run into a question that hasn't been updated and we can't answer it without more information and there's a comment then I usually vote to close, but I don't purposely go after questions after an X date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I flagged that for closure first because it appeared **abandoned**. We did loads of these during the last big cleanup and I remember the consensus being to flag as too-localized when a question appeared abandoned. Different users had different time ranges for defining abandoned, there is no 'official' definition.

I also noted the unusually low 0% accept rate of the asker and so looked at the rest of their questions and last 'seen' time, flagging several more which are now also closed. As with all my flagging & voting decisions, it comes down to a judgement call, an opinion. The fact that four others similarly voted helps validate this, but with such a small sample size I admit it isn't statistically significant.

For this or any other closed questions that interest you, feel free to 'ping' me in chat or send an email (details easy to find through my profile). I'll be happy to vote to re-open a question so you can add something new to it. If that doesn't appeal to you, just ask the same question again with whatever new details you can add.